# iframe resize issue (constant flickering) in ios?

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe

I'm trying to embed chess games from http://chess.gallery into one of my client's sites. The embed javascript sets up the listener and the embed page sends a message to resize as suggested by other stackoverflow posts. It works well (cross domain etc) on all the browsers. But on ios (both safari and chrome) this test page constantly flickers even though I'm not interacting with it as if safari is changing the width of the iframe constantly. Here is the test page.

http://chess.gallery/extensions/embed/index.html

I have spent lot of time on this and couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to this open iOS safari issue: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=149264

Update: this is fixed as of iOS 13